# QtT How To Save Data/State When Changing Central Widgets In QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have inherited the QmainWindow class to use as the mainwindow for the application that I am building.
I have set the central widget as a pointer to another class, that I have created.

```
//main window constructor
postEntryWidget = 0; // null pointer to another class that extends QWidget
dataEntryWidget = new Data_Entry_Widget; //extends QWidget
setCentralWidget(dataEntryWidget); //set the widget in the main window
```

When the user clicks on an action, this sets the central widget to another pointer to another widget class.

```
/*
 *this is the implementation of the slot that would be connected to the QAction
 *connected to the postEntryWidget slot
 */
if(!postEntryWidget)
    postEntryWidget = new Post_Entry_Widget;
setCentralWidget(postEntryWidget);

/*
 *this is the implementation of the slot that would be connected to the QAction
 *connected to the dataEntryWidget slot
 */
if(!dataEntryWidget)
    dataEntryWidget = new Post_Entry_Widget;
setCentralWidget(dataEntryWidget);
```

This breaks when switching back and forth between views. And If I add a null point to the preceding view I lose the data when I go back to that view.

```
 /*
 *this is the implementation of the slot that would be connected to the QAction
 *connected to the postEntryWidget slot
 */
dataEntryWidget = 0; //set the previous widget to a null pointer but loses data
if(!postEntryWidget)
    postEntryWidget = new Post_Entry_Widget;
setCentralWidget(postEntryWidget);
```

How would I keep the state between the two views without creating a custom data structure or is this bad practice.  I am most familiar with php and web dev so I am not sure if this is even the best way to go about this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what your goal is.  But if you are trying to permit someone the ability to go back to something they were working on, then perhaps you'd be better off using a tab widget instead of hiding the existence of that work?

[QTabWidget documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtabwidget.html)

[Qt Tabbed Dialog example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/dialogs-tabdialog.html)

So you'd make that your central widget, and plug the `Post_Entry_Widget` and `Data_Entry_Widget` instances under that.  An advantage of that is that Qt manages the tab switching for you.

If you don't want tabs there is also a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstackedwidget.html), which just lets you programmatically switch between a set of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated than it seems. The problem is, that when `setCentralWidget()` is called, current `centralWidget()` gets deleted. In order to preserve its contents, you need to remove it from the window by reparenting it to `NULL` or `0`. Try to change your code to:

```
if(!postEntryWidget)
    postEntryWidget = new Post_Entry_Widget;
if (centralWidget()) centralWidget()->setParent(0); //reparent if exists
setCentralWidget(postEntryWidget);

/*
...
*/

if(!dataEntryWidget)
    dataEntryWidget = new Post_Entry_Widget;
if (centralWidget()) centralWidget()->setParent(0); //reparent if exists
setCentralWidget(dataEntryWidget);
```

Comment: Taken from Qt docs:

`void QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget * widget)`

Sets the given widget to be the main window's central widget.

Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.